# How can I detect which antibody is produced by the B cell?

Tags: immunology, immune-system

In the primary immune response, IgM is produced (in addition to IgD ). In the secondary immune response, various types of antibodies are produced.

So how do I detect which antibody a B cell is producing at a particlular time?

Answer (score 1):

The major antibody in the second exposure is IgG and in the first exposure it is IgM. IgG and IgM would be produced by Plasma Cells, which are effector B-Cells activated by Cytokines.

If you want to see which antibodies (not just antibody types) are produced by the B-Cell, I would suggest transforming a GFP gene into a Naive B cell and using a Restriction Endonuclease and DNA Ligase to insert the GFP gene to the 5'-end of the Constant (C) region of the Antibody producing gene. Then, you could see which Antibodies are produced by B-cells since the Antibodies would fluoresce.

**Note**: I am currently in high school so I don't have much experience with Immunology, so there might be a few things wrong about my answer. However, I tried my best to answer the question. Hope this helps!!